# How do I add a reflection to a UILabel. IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, reflection, uilabel

(newbie) question here. Searched but could not find this specific answer anywhere.... 
I want to add a reflection (and a glow if possible) to a UILabel. I saw apple's reflection project code but it works for a UIImage not label.

just adding it to a simple clock:

```
- (void)runTimer                    //Starts a timer which messages runClock every 0.5sec
{
    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(runClock)
                                              userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)runClock
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] 
                                  autorelease]; NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    // This will produce a time that looks like "12:15:00 PM". 
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; 

    [clockLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];   
}
```

Comment: what does the posted code have to do with your question?

Comment: Can you please post the link to Apple's reflection project code? I was looking for adding a glow effect to an UIImage and it seems like this might come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: the code for reflecting a UIImageviewhttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reflection/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @6NSString... just thought it would help to put as much info as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article on how to generate reflections of any UI element or group of elements. The canned technique can be dropped into your project and is really easy to use. Source code and the article can be found at http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/08/no-fuss-reflections/

Comment: still works fine (just remove dealloc thing). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way would be subclassing UILabel and override the drawRect method using quartz2d

here's where you and quartz2d can get to know each other a little better.
[here's where you and quartz2d can get to know each other a little better.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks, I can try to give that a shot.